# ScriptAlias - right configuration of VirtualHost

Tags: apache2, cgi, virtualhost, apache-modules

I have some sort of problem with Apache(apache2)
configuration for making `cgi-scripts` working

This configuration is working perfectly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ejudge

        ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" /var/www/ejudge/cgi-bin/
        Alias /ejudge/ /var/www/ejudge/
        DirectoryIndex cgi-bin/new-register

        <Directory /var/www/ejudge/cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +Includes
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But I need that `ScriptAlias` be as `/ejudge/cgi-bin/` because I need to execute them only on that path (like `http://example.com/ejudge/cgi-bin/`, not `http://exapmle.com/cgi-bin/`)

Please help if this possible

(If there is an error in the text, please correct (I have some problems with english))

Comment: What happens when you simply change it?

Comment: When change to `/ejudge/cgi-bin/` it's doesnt work

Comment: add `ScriptAlias` to your site's .conf file. see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html